# Content is not matching with the routing after refreshing

Tags: angular

I have multiple tabs in one of my setting module which further have nested tabs.
I do not want to duplicate the code so I made a routing file inside which I have this route.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: SettingsComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'my-account',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        component: MyAccountComponent
      },
      { path: 'my-account', component: MyAccountComponent },
      { path: 'apps', component: AppsComponent }
    ]
  }
];
```

this is the code of setting.html

```
<div class="AnalyticsBody">

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs pt-1" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item" (click)="goToMyAccount()">
      <a class="nav-link active font14 pb-2 mr-4" id="myaccount-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#myAccount" role="tab"
        aria-controls="myAccount" aria-selected="true">My Account</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" (click)="gotToApps()">

      <a class="nav-link font14 pb-2 mr-4" id="apps-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#apps" role="tab" aria-controls="apps"
        aria-selected="false">Apps</a>

    </li>

  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content grey-bg settings" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="myAccount" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="myAccount">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So when the url will be `setting` then my `settingComponent` will load which have the layout of my tabs and it will redirect to `setting/my-account` which has then content. it will work unless if I go to `setting/apps` and then if I refresh it then instead of seeing `setting/apps` content, I will see the content of `setting/my-account`
how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the 'default' route last. They are processed in order.

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: '',
  component: SettingsComponent,
  children: [      
    { path: 'my-account', component: MyAccountComponent },
    { path: 'apps', component: AppsComponent },
    {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: 'my-account',
      pathMatch: 'full',
      component: MyAccountComponent
    },
  ]
 }
];
```